# Update already created Fragments in ViewPager based on event

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, rx-java

I have an Activity (extends AppCompatActivity), ViewPager with adapter (extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter) with 8 fragments. The fragments get data from ViewModel where I use LiveData. By default ViewPager creates 2 fragments simultaneously, i.e. when the 1st fragment is visible, the 2nd is already passed the onResume state.

My problem is - when a user changes rating in RatingBar in one fragment, the already created fragments do not get updated with the new data. The other fragments (not adjacent to the changed one) do get the new value.

My question is - how to update the data in already created fragments? Should I use Rx Java (subscribers) or there is standard Android solution to it?

Code:

Fragment onResume contains:

```
/* Rating Bar */
    ratingBar.setIsIndicator(false);
    detailViewModel.getRating().observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
            try {
                ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat(s));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                Log.i("NumberFormatException", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });

    ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(final RatingBar ratingBar, float v, boolean b) {
            ratingBar.setRating(v);
            detailViewModel.setRating(v);
        }
    });
```

Comment: After looking at Google Codelab I found out that the mistake was on my side - I was not implementing LiveData correctly. Codelabs have an example on how to update fragments in real time:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-lifecycles/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#5

https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-lifecycles/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/lifecycles/step5_solution/Fragment_step5.java